# Angular state provider match cases in url (regex)

Tags: regex, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've created an SPA with multiple ui-views using the state provider.

I have a few url match cases, however I want to make them match not just on an explicit url, example:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, paths) {
    var base = paths.static.views + 'modules/';

    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url : '/',
        views : {
            'home' : {
                templateUrl : base + 'home/_layout.html',
                controller: function() {
                    console.log('home');
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .state('foo', {
        url : '/foo',
        views : {
            'foo' : {
                templateUrl : base + 'foo/_layout.html',
                controller: function() {
                    console.log('foo');
                }
            }
        },
    })
    .state('bar', {
        url : '/bar*',
        views : {
            'bar' : {
                templateUrl : base + 'bar/_layout.html',
                controller: function() {
                    console.log('bar');
                }
            }
        },
    })
    .state('dog', {
        url : '/dog*',
        views : {
            'dog' : {
                templateUrl : base + 'dog/_layout.html',
                controller: function() {
                    console.log('dog');
                }
            }
        },
    });
});
```

So if I navigate to /foo it works, however if my server has a re-write rule (which it does in some cases) it will re-write it to /foo/ and the match case no longer fires.

I've tried adding `{url : '/foo*'}` but that didn't work either.

I would really like to fix this!

Comment: You server shouldn't be rewriting those URLs. Sounds like a configuration issue

Comment: I dont' have control over this and surely this is possible because with the routeProvider I could do something like /:page* and it would work, but doesn't seem to work here @Phil